# Adding User Groups to Teams

Tags: liferay

I'm using a hook to create a Team for each User Group that is created. (Eventually there will be an LDAP import that does this all at once)

My TeamServiceWrapperImpl is getting called from the group creation just fine when I create a user group, but I don't see a new team being created.

Here's my AddUserGroupImpl method:

```
@Override
public UserGroup addUserGroup(String name, String description, ServiceContext serviceContext)  throws PortalException, SystemException{
    super.addUserGroup(name, description, serviceContext);
    id = this.getUserGroup(name).getGroupId();
    name = this.getUserGroup(name).getName();
    System.out.println("You've created User Group: " + name);
    System.out.println("The user group name is " + name);

    TeamServiceUtil.addTeam(id, name, teamDescription);
    return null;
}
```

and my TeamServiceWrapperImpl:

```
public Team addTeam(long groupId, String name, String description) throws PortalException, SystemException{
   System.out.println("Adding a Team from inside the TeamService Class");
   return super.addTeam(groupId, name, description);
}
```

and lastly, my liferay-hook.xml:

```
<hook>
       <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
       <custom-jsp-dir>/META-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
       <service>
          <service-type>com.liferay.portal.service.UserGroupService</service-type>
          <service-impl>com.bofa.AddUserGroupToTeamImpl</service-impl>
       </service>
       <service>
          <service-type>com.liferay.portal.service.TeamService</service-type>
          <service-impl>com.bofa.TeamServiceWrapperImpl</service-impl>
       </service>

</hook>
```

Any ideas as to why my teams aren't getting created, even though the addTeam method is being called?